# Написал табы первый раз выдает ошибка помогите найти

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

https://jsfiddle.net/ghvxk3sr/50/

```js
var ListItem = document.querySelectorAll('.list__item');
var tab = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');

for(var i = 0; i < ListItem.length; i++){
 ListItem[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
   for(var u = 0; u < ListItem.length; u++){
     ListItem[u].classList.remove('active');
      tab[u].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }) 
  this.classList.add('active');
  tab[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.list{
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: center;
}
.list__item{
  margin-left: 30px;
}
a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.dn{
  display: none;
}

.active {color: red; border-bottom: 1px solid #045acf}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#">Лондон</a>
  </li>
   <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#">Париж</a>
  </li>
   <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#">Рим</a>
  </li>
   <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#">Брюсель</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<div class="tab dn">Лондон - 1111</div>
<div class="tab dn">Париж - 2222</div>
<div class="tab dn">Рим - 3333</div>
<div class="tab dn">Брюсель - 4444</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас 2 ошибки,

Эти 2 строчки почему-то вне слушателя

```
this.classList.add('active');
tab[i].style.display = "block";
```

ошибка с замыканием на переменную, в цикле

```
tab[i]
```

я обошел её за счет вынесения навешивания слушателя в функцию, таким образом создав отдельную переменную i, не ту что меняется в теле цикла, а аргумент функции l.

```js
var ListItem = document.querySelectorAll('.list__item');
var tab = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');

for(var i = 0; i < ListItem.length; i++){
 l(ListItem, i)
}

function l(ListItem, i){
  ListItem[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
   for(var u = 0; u < ListItem.length; u++){
     ListItem[u].classList.remove('active');
      tab[u].style.display = 'none';
    }
    this.classList.add('active');
    tab[i].style.display = "block";
  }) 
}
```

```css
.list{
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: center;
}
.list__item{
  margin-left: 30px;
}
a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.dn{
  display: none;
}

.active {color: red; border-bottom: 1px solid #045acf}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#">Лондон</a>
  </li>
   <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#">Париж</a>
  </li>
   <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#">Рим</a>
  </li>
   <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#">Брюсель</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<div class="tab dn">Лондон - 1111</div>
<div class="tab dn">Париж - 2222</div>
<div class="tab dn">Рим - 3333</div>
<div class="tab dn">Брюсель - 4444</div>
```

Comment: @Leks https://habr.com/ru/post/142351/